# ¿Cómo puedo poner preguntas aleatorias en un "cuestionario" en java?

Tags: java

> Tengo este código, en el que cree una clase "Menú" para mostrar las preguntas y las opciones de respuesta, pero necesito que las dos respuestas incorrectas y la correcta aparezcan en lugares diferentes, es decir que cada vez que el programa lo corra me aparezcan lugares diferentes ( que la respuesta correcta esté en el lugar 1 o 2 o 3. les dejo el enunciado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class JOp
{ 
private static  int Menu ( )
{
    int opc;
    String mnu = "¿Quien fue el primer hombre en pisar la luna? \n\n" + 
                 "     1. Elon Musk \n" +
                 "     2. Neil Armstrong \n" +
                 "     3. Jeff Bezos\n\n"+
                 " Digite la opción deseada: \n";
        
    opc = Integer.parseInt ( JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, mnu ) );
    if ( opc <= 3 && opc > 0 )
        return opc;
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opción no válida, intente de nuevo por favor");
        return Menu ( );
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int opcion;
    opcion = Menu();
    if  (opcion == 1)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Respuesta incorrecta, la respuesta correcta era Neil Armstrong.");
    else
    {
        if (opcion == 2)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Excelente!");
        else
        {
            if (opcion == 3)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Respuesta incorrecta, la respuesta correcta era Neil Armstrong.");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega en el cuerpo de tu pregunta cual es el problema que tienes, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos

Comment: Hola, ya la edité, gracias.

Comment: Primero que nada tendrías que Definir la estructura de cómo vas a almacenar las preguntas y respuestas que puedan ser seleccionadas, personalmente te aconsejaría investigar más acerca de Objetos y Listas.

Comment: Te recomiendo usar el api de colecciones y los métodos estáticos de Collection

Answer (score 0):

Hola en base a la estructura del problema he realizado el siguiente codigo basandome en la estructura de codigo que ha presentado. Cualquier duda me la puede hacer conocer.

Clase Main la misma que contiene el metodo main para la ejecucion del programa.

```
package tester;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // creando la respuesta a la pregunta a presentar;
        RespuestaCorrecta respuestaCorrecta = new RespuestaCorrecta("Neil Armstrong");
        // creando las respuestas que se mostraran en pantalla
        ArrayList<RespuestaMultiple> respuestaMultiples = new ArrayList<RespuestaMultiple>();
        RespuestaMultiple respuestaMultiple = new RespuestaMultiple("Elon Musk");
        RespuestaMultiple respuestaMultiple2 = new RespuestaMultiple("Neil Armstrong");
        RespuestaMultiple respuestaMultiple3 = new RespuestaMultiple("Jeff Bezos");
        respuestaMultiples.add(respuestaMultiple);
        respuestaMultiples.add(respuestaMultiple2);
        respuestaMultiples.add(respuestaMultiple3);
        // creando la pregunta con su respectiva respuesta correcta y su lista de
        // posibles respuestas.
        String preguntaString = "¿Quien fue el primer hombre en pisar la luna?";
        Pregunta pregunta = new Pregunta(preguntaString, respuestaCorrecta, respuestaMultiples);

        /*
         * Ya de ahi si quieres mas preguntas lo unico que deberas hacer crearlas asi
         * mismo y las vas agregando a una lista de preguntas y para hacerlo mas
         * dinamico puedes ir seleccionando de manera aleatoria y las vas presentando y
         * si quieres seguir avanzando el juegutio pues te recomiendo que las preguntas
         * que vas usando las vayas quitando de esa lista principal de preguntas y la
         * mandes a otra , y despues verificas si ya la principal ya no tiene preguntas
         * ,pues muestras un mensaje que ha ganado el juego e incluso eso haria que no
         * salgan preguntas repetidas, y al mostrar el mensaje que se acabo el juego que
         * gano o que se yo, pues le cierras la ventana de juego.
         */
        int opcion;
        opcion = menu(pregunta);
        mostrarRespuestaCorrecta(opcion, pregunta);
    }

    private static int menu(Pregunta obPregunta) {
        int opc;
        String mnu = generarPregunta(obPregunta);
        opc = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, mnu));
        if (opc <= 3 && opc > 0)
            return opc;
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opción no válida, intente de nuevo por favor");
            return menu(obPregunta);
        }
    }

    private static String generarPregunta(Pregunta obPregunta) {
        String preguntaString = null;
        String respuesta1 = null, respuesta2 = null, respuesta3 = null;
        ArrayList<RespuestaMultiple> respuestaMultiples = obPregunta.getRespuestaMultiples();
        Collections.shuffle(respuestaMultiples);
        for (int i = 0; i < respuestaMultiples.size(); i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                respuesta1 = "1. " + respuestaMultiples.get(i).getRespuesta();
            }

            if (i == 1) {
                respuesta2 = "2. " + respuestaMultiples.get(i).getRespuesta();
            }
            if (i == 2) {
                respuesta3 = "3. " + respuestaMultiples.get(i).getRespuesta();
            }
        }
        preguntaString = obPregunta.getPregunta() + "\n" + respuesta1 + "\n" + respuesta2 + "\n" + respuesta3;
        return preguntaString;
    }

    private static void mostrarRespuestaCorrecta(int opcion, Pregunta obPregunta) {
        int op = opcion - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < obPregunta.getRespuestaMultiples().size(); i++) {
            if (i == op) {
                if (obPregunta.getRespuestaMultiples().get(i).getRespuesta().trim()
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(obPregunta.getRespuestaCorrecta().getRespuesta())) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Excelente!");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Respuesta incorrecta, la respuesta correcta era: "
                            + obPregunta.getRespuestaCorrecta().getRespuesta());
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Clase Pregunta, la cual contiene las respuestas que se van a presentar y la respuesta correcta de la pregunta.

```
package tester;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Pregunta {
    private String pregunta;
    private RespuestaCorrecta respuestaCorrecta;
    private ArrayList<RespuestaMultiple> respuestaMultiples;

    public Pregunta(String pregunta, RespuestaCorrecta respuestaCorrecta,
            ArrayList<RespuestaMultiple> respuestaMultiples) {
        this.pregunta = pregunta;
        this.respuestaCorrecta = respuestaCorrecta;
        this.respuestaMultiples = respuestaMultiples;
    }

    public String getPregunta() {
        return pregunta;
    }

    public void setPregunta(String pregunta) {
        this.pregunta = pregunta;
    }

    public RespuestaCorrecta getRespuestaCorrecta() {
        return respuestaCorrecta;
    }

    public void setRespuestaCorrecta(RespuestaCorrecta respuestaCorrecta) {
        this.respuestaCorrecta = respuestaCorrecta;
    }

    public ArrayList<RespuestaMultiple> getRespuestaMultiples() {
        return respuestaMultiples;
    }

    public void setRespuestaMultiples(ArrayList<RespuestaMultiple> respuestaMultiples) {
        this.respuestaMultiples = respuestaMultiples;
    }

}
```

Clase respuestaCorrecta.

```
package tester;

public class RespuestaCorrecta {
    private String respuesta;

    public RespuestaCorrecta(String respuesta) {
        this.respuesta = respuesta;
    }

    public String getRespuesta() {
        return respuesta;
    }

    public void setRespuesta(String respuesta) {
        this.respuesta = respuesta;
    }
}
```

Clase respuestaAleatoria, en esta clase se alamcenan las posibles respuestas mismas que seran enlazadas a la pregunta a traves de una lista como se mostro con anterioridad.

```
package tester;

public class RespuestaMultiple {
    private String respuesta;

    public RespuestaMultiple(String respuesta) {
        this.respuesta = respuesta;
    }

    public String getRespuesta() {
        return respuesta;
    }

    public void setRespuesta(String respuesta) {
        this.respuesta = respuesta;
    }
    
}
```

Espero esto te haya ayudado.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!

Comment: De nada, éxitos.